# Opciones del 1 al 10 en un recyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Estoy haciendo una pregunta de calificación con opciones del 1 al 10 pero tengo una problema en el evento "setOnClickListener()" para setear los background si está seleccionado o deseleccionado por la posición que pe da el método onBindViewHolder() del RecyclerAdapter. Espero que entiendan mi pregunta y me puedan ayudar a resolverlo, aquí les dejo el código que uso.

MainActivity:

```
package bitlicon.preguntacinco;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearSnapHelper;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_items);

        final List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemList.add(new Item(0, "0"));
        itemList.add(new Item(1, "1"));
        itemList.add(new Item(2, "2"));
        itemList.add(new Item(3, "3"));
        itemList.add(new Item(4, "4"));
        itemList.add(new Item(5, "5"));
        itemList.add(new Item(6, "6"));
        itemList.add(new Item(7, "7"));
        itemList.add(new Item(8, "8"));
        itemList.add(new Item(9, "9"));
        itemList.add(new Item(10, "10"));

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        new LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        final ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList, recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(1);

        itemAdapter.setOnItemSizeListener(new ItemAdapter.OnItemSizeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSize(int size) {
                itemAdapter.setOnItemSizeListener(null);
                int padding = (recyclerView.getMeasuredWidth() - size)  / 2;
                recyclerView.setPadding(padding, 0, padding, 0);
            }
        });

        itemAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
                int itemID = -1;
                if (position != -1)
                    itemID = itemList.get(position).getItemID();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(itemID), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Item:

```
package bitlicon.preguntacinco;

public class Item {

    private int itemID;
    private String number;

    public Item(int itemID, String number) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getItemID() {
        return itemID;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

ItemAdapter:

```
package bitlicon.preguntacinco;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private int positionItem = -1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<Item> items;

    private boolean hacerCambio = false;
    private int itemCambio = -1;

    private OnItemSizeListener onItemSizeListener;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public ItemAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> items, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
}

    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
}

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.textView.setId(items.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemID());
        viewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getNumber());

        if (hacerCambio && itemCambio == viewHolder.textView.getId()) {
            ViewHolder item = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(itemCambio);
            if (item != null) {
                item.fondo.setScaleX(0);
                item.fondo.setScaleY(0);

                item.fondo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_unselect));
                item.textView.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.darker_gray)));

                item.fondo.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(activity, android.R.interpolator.bounce)).setDuration(600);

                hacerCambio = false;
                itemCambio = -1;
            }
        }

        viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onItemClickListener != null)
                    onItemClickListener.onClick(viewHolder. getAdapterPosition(), viewHolder);

                if (positionItem == -1) {
                    positionItem = viewHolder.textView.getId();
                    ViewHolder opcion = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(positionItem);
                    opcion.fondo.setScaleX(0);
                    opcion.fondo.setScaleY(0);

                    opcion.fondo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable( activity, R.drawable.background_select));
                    opcion.textView.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf( ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.white)));

                    opcion.fondo.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(activity,android.R.interpolator.bounce)).setDuration(600);
                } else if (positionItem == viewHolder.textView.getId()) {
                    ViewHolder opcion = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(positionItem);
                    opcion.fondo.setScaleX(0);
                    opcion.fondo.setScaleY(0);

                    opcion.fondo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_unselect));
                    opcion.textView.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf( ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.darker_gray)));

                    opcion.fondo.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(activity,android.R.interpolator.bounce)).setDuration(600);
                    positionItem = -1;
                } else {
                    int itemActual = viewHolder.textView.getId();
                    ViewHolder opcion = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(itemActual);
                    opcion.fondo.setScaleX(0);
                    opcion.fondo.setScaleY(0);

                    opcion.fondo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable( activity, R.drawable.background_select));
                    opcion.textView.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf( ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.white)));

                    opcion.fondo.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(activity,android.R.interpolator.bounce)).setDuration(600);

                    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(positionItem);

                    if (holder != null) {
                        holder.fondo.setScaleX(0);
                        holder.fondo.setScaleY(0);

                        holder.fondo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_unselect));
                        holder.textView.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat. getColor(activity, android.R.color.darker_gray)));

                        holder.fondo.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(activity, android.R.interpolator.bounce)).setDuration(600);
                    } else {
                        hacerCambio = true;
                        itemCambio = positionItem;
                    }

                    positionItem = viewHolder.textView.getId();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemSizeListener(OnItemSizeListener onItemSizeListener) {
        this.onItemSizeListener = onItemSizeListener;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textView;
        private View rootView;
        private View fondo;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            rootView = view;
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.opcion);
            fondo = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.fondo);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemSizeListener {
        void onItemSize(int size);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(int position, ItemAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por lo que entiendo quieres tener 10 elementos y que cuando seleccionen uno, el background de ese elemento cambie para indicar que esta seleccionado solo ese y el anterior quede igual a los demas.

Cambia tu onBindViewHolder a esto:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    viewHolder.textView.setId(items.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemID());
    viewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getNumber());

    if(seleccionado == position){
        viewHolder.fondo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable( activity, R.drawable.background_select));
    }else {
        viewHolder.fondo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_unselect));
    }

    viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (onItemClickListener != null)
                onItemClickListener.onClick(position, viewHolder);
            seleccionado= position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

puedes mantener una variable con el nombre que quieras en en este caso yo la he llamado seleccionado y la inicio con -1, luego cuando se ejecute el `onItemClickListener` se cambia seleccionado a la posición a la que le dieron click y llamamos el `notifyDataSetChanged();` que básicamente hará que todos los elementos visibles pasen por el `onBindViewHolder`volviendo a pintar el background de cada elemento.

espero haberte ayudado.